# How to test for access prohibited in Cypress?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

How do I test that if I try to visit a page that I'm not authorised for I get a 403 response?

This is what I'm trying so far:

```
cy.visit('/sys-ops')
cy.location('pathname').should('eq', '/error/unauthorized')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like this

```
describe('showcase Cypress request', () => {

    it('checks for 403', () => {

        cy.request({
            url: '/my-unauthorized-url',
            followRedirect: false,
            failOnStatusCode: false
        }).then((resp) => {
            expect(resp.status).to.eq(403)
        })
    })
})
```

[image]

Find more details here https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Request-a-page-while-disabling-auto-redirect